# What's google's balloon estimated LTE radiated power at ground ?

Tags: rf, radiation, regulations

Google loon, google's internet balloon project , is transmitting from a height of 20km , and has a cell radius of 40km, and uses LTE.

What would be the EIRP ? would be one such that EIRP at near ground level just below the satellite is equal the EIRP of regular LTE ? Or some other regulation ?

Comment: Since GLoon share the ISM band spectrum, and it is not considered as WiFi (801....) there is EIRP restrictions to 30dBm (4W) for Point-to-Ground communication and up to 200W for Point-to-Point (with some Transmitter- Antenna combinations). Since baloon-to-ballon communication is done mainly via optic links and battery it is limited to about 100W (night working) so this 4W it is possible.

Comment: So there's no  consideration of how high the balloon is flying? Why?

Comment: Even lower power with existing 802.11a (5GHz) reception cards gives bitrates of 2Mbps in terrestrial long range WiFi. The 2.5GHz frequency also have higher data carrying capabilities. The oxygen absorption it is an issue, but as far as I know they focused more in interballon communication and moving control, as well as the dynamic bandwidth management. This is my perception, since they didn’t  give any numerical information even on their applied patent.

Comment: I'm more interested in communication to ground. And they use LTE for that according to recent publications.